# find list of users based on multiple condition using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to know how to use aggregation to perform this.
find userId list  who perform add to cart and item view event more then 2 times

Collection name event.

```
{
_id:1,
name:"Add To Cart",
userId:1
}
{
_id:2,
name:"Searched",
userId:2
}
{
_id:3,
name:"Add To Cart",
userId:1
}
{
_id:4,
name:"Item View",
userId:1
}
{
_id:5,
name:"Add To Cart",
userId:2
}
{
_id:6,
name:"Item View",
userId:1
}
```

my query-

```
db.getCollection("event").aggregate([ {$match:{$or:[{"name":"Add to 
Cart"},{"name":"Item Viewed"}]}}, 
{$group:{_id:  {userId:"$userId",name:"$name"},count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gte:2}}},
{$group:   {_id:"$_id.userId",event:{$push:"$_id.name"}}} ,
{$project:{size:{$size:"$event"}}},  
{$match:{size:{$gte:2}}}
]).pretty();
```

output expected -from above collection 
     {userId:1}
I want only those userId who perform Add to cart and Item view event(both) more then 2 times.

Comment: what output do you want from above collection?

Comment: Your $match stage has a typo. Use `{$match:{$or:[{"name":"Add To Cart"},{"name":"Item View"}]}}` and all should work,

Answer (score 0):

Here is Full Query ,

```
db.Test.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [

        {
            $group: {
              "_id": {
                "userId": "$userId",
                "name": "$name"
              },
              "count": {
                "$sum": 1
              }
            }
        },


        {
            $match: {
              "count": {
                "$gte": 2
              }
            }
        },


        {
            $group: {
              "_id": "$_id.userId",
              "event": {
                "$push": "$_id.name"
              }
            }
        },


        {
            $project: {
              "size": {
                "$size": "$event"
              }
            }
        },


        {
            $match: {
              "size": {
                "$gte": 2
              }
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

You will get your userId in _id field.